# Printing to stdout writes into an opened file using f95

Tags: file, printing, io, fortran

So let's say that I have `file1.txt` opened in `unit=5` and at the same time I have `file2.txt` opened in `unit=6`. And then I call `print *, "something"`. Now seemingly, `"something"` does not get printed as an output but gets written to the second file. Why does that happen and how can I avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: I am using f95 @francescalus

Comment: It is by GCC @francescalus (GNU Fortran (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127)

Comment: In particular, note [IanH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38546989/3157076) to the linked question.  In your case `5` and `6` are very likely to the special ones.  You should avoid using these numbers, and because you have a recent version of gfortran `open(newunit=...` is a viable approach.

Comment: Is there any number that could be considered as safe? For instance "any number between x and y is safe" ? @francescalus Thanks

Comment: Any positive number could be preconnected in a way you don't like. You can use the module `iso_fortran_env` to see which are "special", but really `newunit` is the way to go with new code.  (What is preconnected and where is entirely at the whim of the compiler vendor.  It could change from day to day, even.)